# При использовании центровки во Flexbox - "съедаются" первые элементы

Tags: html, css3, flexbox, выравнивание, alignment

Появилась задача: выстроить все колонки в 1 ряд без переносов - с расчетом на горизонтальную прокрутку страницы.

Использовал флексбокс, и вроде всё хорошо было - пока не решил добавить центрирование `justify-content: center` для больших экранов. Тогда на маленьких первые блоки начали съедаться.

С чем это связано и как это побороть?

PS: Желательно без медиазапросов (для универсальности).

https://codepen.io/AleLit/pen/ZEJPZoG

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center; /* начинают "съедаться" первые блоки  */
}
.inner {
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #743e1e;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
   <div class="inner">1</div>
   <div class="inner">2</div>
   <div class="inner">3</div>
   <div class="inner">4</div>
   <div class="inner">5</div>
   <div class="inner">6</div>
   <div class="inner">7</div>
   <div class="inner">8</div>
   <div class="inner">9</div>
   <div class="inner">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @soledar10, противоречивая задача - как раз самое интересное: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1353672/208926

Comment: Где же тут противоречие? На больших экранах нужна центровка. На маленьких, центровка не актуальна, но необходимо чтобы все блоки были доступны для просмотра. По моему вполне здравый запрос.

Comment: @Александр не правильно понял задачу, добавил вариант

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky не правильно понял задачу, добавил вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужен промежуточный флекс-блок. Ему передаём свойства `gap` и `justify-content`. И добавляем `flex-grow: 1`, чтобы растягивался до ширины экрана.

А внешний блок просто остаётся флексом, чтобы у промежуточного `flex-grow` действовал.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/VwzJdpz

```css
/* суть дела */
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center; 
}

/* для красоты */
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h4 {
  margin: 12px 0 6px;
}
h4:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.middle {
  gap: 10px;
}
.inner {
  background: #369;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 45px;
  min-width: 180px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Если мало элементов, то они по центру:</h4>
<div class="main">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h4>А если много, то прокручиваем страницу:</h4>
<div class="main">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
    <div class="inner">5</div>
    <div class="inner">6</div>
    <div class="inner">7</div>
    <div class="inner">8</div>
    <div class="inner">9</div>
    <div class="inner">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сууупер! Спасибо огромное, работает! ))

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием `display: grid`

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 250px);  
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #743e1e;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
    <div class="inner">5</div>
    <div class="inner">6</div>
    <div class="inner">7</div>
    <div class="inner">8</div>
    <div class="inner">9</div>
    <div class="inner">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```